# Configurar fichero log4j.properties en web.xml

Tags: maven, log4j

Estoy utilizando la libreria `log4j` en mi proyecto `Maven`.

Lo primero, no se si se tiene que guardar en `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\resource\` o en   `\src\main\resource`

Para que la aplicacion detecte dicho fichero(lo he visto en foros) lo he configurado asi en `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>es.aaa.n005.utils.Log4jInit</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/log4j.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

He maven-clean y un Maven-Install. Arranco el servidor en local y al ejecutar mi url Localhost en la consola de eclipse me aparece lo siguiente:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file
>   [C:\KK\workspace\desarrollo\salesforcews\salesforcews-WEB\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources/WEB-INF/resource/log4j.properties].
>   [err] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\KK\workspace\desarrollo\salesforcews\salesforcews-WEB\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\WEB-INF\resource\log4j.properties
>   (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

Fichero `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

El properties contiene lo siguiente:

> log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLA,ARCHIVO
>
> log4j.appender.CONSOLA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.CONSOLA.Target=System.out
>   log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.ARCHIVO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.File=log/archivoSalesforcews.log
>   log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.MaxBackupIndex=5
>   log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.MaxFileSize=2MB

El método de la Clase que intenta convocar el propertie es el siguiente:

```
public void init(){
        String prefix = getServletContext().getRealPath(Constantes.BARRA);
        String file = getInitParameter(Constantes.LOG4JINIT);

        if(file != null){
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(prefix + file);
        }
    }
```

Donde `Constantes.BARRA` vale `"/"` y `Constantes.LOG4JINIT` vale `log4j-init-file`

Me pondriais indicar como debo configurar el `web.xml` u otra cosa para que reconozca el `properties`? Si necesitais mas informacion, por favor decirmelo.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: puedes publicar la configuración del pom.xml y del log4j.properties para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: edita tu pregunta y colocalo arriba, donde planteas la pregunta y elimina los comentarios para evitar votos negativos

Comment: ¿como edito la pregunta?

Comment: click en el botón editar y complementa el código

Comment: Hecho muchas gracias @Angabo

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a editar el `pom.xml`

De la siguiente manera:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Lo he añadido debajo de la dependencia [tag:<groupId>log4j</groupId>] pero sigue fallando por lo mismo, Aparte del [tag:pom.xml] debo añadir [tag:org.apache.logging.log4j] en otro sitio? muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes la clase que llama al .properties desde tu códgo?puede ser que te falte algo como esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528287/log4j-could-not-read-configuration-file

Comment: Añado el metodo para convocar el propertie