# Localizar src/main/resource en Maven cuando ejecuto

Tags: maven, log4j

Abro en paralelo esta pregunta en relación a esta (que ya esta solucionada):

[Configurar fichero log4j.properties en web.xml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262475/configurar-fichero-log4j-properties-en-web-xml)

Tengo el fichero `log4j.properties` en `src/main/resource` y quiero localizarlo cuando ejecuto la aplicacion pero me sale lo siguiente en la consola:

> [err] java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:log4j.properties (El
>   sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado) [err]     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [err]     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146) [err]    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101) [err]    at
>   es.aaa.n005.utils.Log4jInit.init(Log4jInit.java:26) [err]
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161) [err]
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
>   [err]     at [internal classes]

La clase que ejecuta es la siguiente:

```
public class Log4jInit extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init(){

    String file = getInitParameter(Constantes.LOG4JINIT);

    try{
        if(file != null){
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(file));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

En `web.xml` tengo lo siguiente:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>es.aaa.n005.utils.Log4jInit</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

y en el `pom.xml` :

```
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/resource</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
         <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
```

Me podríais indicar que puede faltar o que esta mal configurado? cualquier duda o aclaración decídmelo y lo veo.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. No he usado nunca un `URI` del tipo `classpath:`, lo que suelo hacer para leer recursos del classpath es usar *Class.getResourceAsStream*. Otra cosa a comprobar es descomprimir el *.war/.ear*, para comprobar que el fichero está y así acotar el problema.

Comment: Hola Juan, tendrías algún ejemplo con `Class.getResourceAsStream?`

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37878/problema-al-leer-archivo-txt-con-java/37894#37894

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene **Constantes.LOG4JINIT**?

Comment: "log4j-init-file", el mismo que la linea `<param-name>` del `web.xml`